# File/directory not found when trying to render matplotlib text with LaTeX

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to render text in matplotlib using LaTeX, so that I can include native-looking plots in my LaTeX documents, as described here: https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/usetex.html

I have LaTeX, dvipng and Ghostscript installed, and I've checked the executables are in my `PATH` (as specified in the matplotlib documentation) but when I run the following test it returns

```
  File "/Users/wilf/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex': 'latex'
```

The test code is just

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

plt.pyplot.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
plt.pyplot.xlabel('x')
plt.pyplot.ylabel('y')
```

I'm not sure why it gives me this error, or how I can fix it.

Comment: Open a terminal window, type `latex`, press Enter. Does latex run then or not?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes it does

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the meantime? I am currently facing the same issues with latex and matplotlib